# Google Image Search API (Deprecated)

Tags: image, api, search, deprecated

As it is stated on their website Google has stopped maintaining the Image search API and it is now deprecated. This is from 2011, as of their policy the API is working for 3 more years before they shut it down. It is now way more than 3 years and the API is working. Does anyone have any information if the API will continue to work and are they shutting it down anytime soon?

Also does this API have any limit to the request per day or anything like that. As i have read the only restriction is the 64 max results per request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The Google Image Search API has been officially deprecated as of May 26, 2011. It will continue to work as per our deprecation policy, but the number of requests you may make per day may be limited. We encourage you to use the [Custom Search API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search), which now supports image search.

https://developers.google.com/image-search/v1/devguide